# How do I interact with people?

Tags: support, user-interface, winter-bash-2015

I'm afraid I'm a little shy, and it's hard for me to find the right way to interact with [the people](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/).

That said, I've tried several things, and nothing is working.

For instance, when I click on one of them, they don't seem to notice.  Waving the cursor over them doesn't alter their behavior either. Clicking and dragging yields no response.

Is this the intended behavior of [these people](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/), or is there a way for me to interact with them?

Comment: Have you tried yelling at them?

Comment: @Shog9 Yes.  And tilting their world this way and that. I'm not going to say that I violently shook them, but I can confirm that violent shaking doesn't alter the situation.

Comment: You imagine them, all the people, just like John Lennon.

Comment: I find it's best to actively listen, and let them show you how they want to communicate.

Comment: I think referring to them as "These People" is offensive to miniature stickmen/women.

Comment: if you view source, you'll see they know less than you might think

Comment: @KateGregory Viewing the source just makes me desire a PCG.SE challenge to create the same effect in fewer bytes...

Comment: I hit one with a hammer, but it didn't get the reaction I was expecting. Now I'm wondering if any of those cyber monday specials are still going on...

Comment: You think they interact for free? Send $100 to Winterbash Headquarters and they'll do anything you want.

Comment: I don't want to make your shyness worse, but have you considered the possibility that they're ignoring you? Maybe you need a new group of people.

Comment: :['](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=3wkIkCyxhUA)(

Comment: [Be careful what you wish for.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=opAJyA-L-fw)

Comment: 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, ?

Comment: Try with some drums, maybe they will move with a good PATA PATA PATA PON.

Comment: A downvote! Apparently I continue to have a problem interacting with people...

Answer (score 11):

I think this is their behavior.

After at least an hour of searching every crook and cranny of the website, spamming my fingers on the keyboard and inspecting the element and using everything I know about computers, the result is none. The people will move by themselves without paying any attention to you or any user (I am not shy by nature).

**EDIT:** You can seemingly change the numbers they make by changing the time on your computer. Seems really fun. Add a few days, and see the number drop dramatically while removing some days will show nothing at all (a bug?)

[image]

[image]

[image]

FYI, chat is a great place to undo your shyness :) .

Comment: FYI, your personal email is displayed on the browser tab. As I didn't see any way to contact you from here, I'd guess that you also don't want to show your email here (just letting you know...)

Comment: Yeah and [presumably] the name of the county in which you live...

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can't interact directly, but I've made is easier to make them obey.

Just click "Run code snippet", put a number, and make them GO.

```js
$(function () {
    $('#btnGO').click(function() {
        var minutes = parseInt($('#txtMinutes').val(), 10);
        if (isNaN(minutes)) {
            alert('Do not make us run NaN, please!');
        } else {
            countdown(new Date().getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#myPlaceholder {position: absolute; top: 5px; left: 5px;  }
body {
            background:#091e2f;
        }
        body, html, div, canvas {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        #fixed {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%
        }
        #container {
            width: 1200px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #town {
         background: #0d2d46 url('//cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/img/bg-dark.png?v=16ca97a8899c') no-repeat center bottom;
         height: 180px;
            background-size:1200px;
        }
        canvas {
        }
        #cover {
            position:absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            height: 450px;
            width: 200px;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #091e2f, rgba(9, 30, 47, 0));
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn-prom.sstatic.net/WinterBash/js/countdown.js?v=73c502a07616"></script>
<div id="myPlaceholder"><input type="text" id="txtMinutes" /><button id="btnGO" type="button">GO</button></div>
<div id="town"></div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="cover"></div>
        <canvas width="1200" height="450"></canvas>
    </div>
```