# The Quest for the Winter Chickens of the Bash

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2015, easter-eggs, chicken

It is that time of the year again, winter is coming, and while all the ponies are busy hanging home-made icicles to the roofs of their houses, here we are again collecting hats and wondering about the eggs they may hide.

Some of the oldest of you, my kind public, may remember an old forgotten tale of the cute [purple unicorn that blessed our lands some years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161331/the-quest-for-the-winter-unicorn-of-the-bash).
Since that old time, back in 2012, bron... I meant, users, have waited for it return, to no avail. The purple one was never saw again.

This year, a single believer was again waiting in the snow, until something happened. What? You are asking me if the unicorn returned??

No, actually someone claimed to have seen a group of chickens near the door of that lonely barn in the WinterBash site logo...  Others said that they saw all the people taking a rest from their snowball fight and forming an heart sitting on the ground...
As you may understand, the trolling is strong in this ones, but we are talking of the SE staff here, so all is possible.

I am here asking again after so long. As anyone notice any strange Easter egg in the Winter Bash site? Are the chicken real or just a troll?
I will try and see if I can find something in the script, until then...

Let the quest for the feathered ones begin!

Comment: ... what?​​​​​​

Comment: Use `<strike>` and `</strike>` for strikethroughs.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 I will try to find the picture again, but someone on the chat claimed that he saw a group of chickens near the barn in the winterbash site banner. Others claimed that the people playing snowball sat down to form an heart... I am trying to see if some of this tales are true and documenting it with some screens.

Comment: @Doorknob冰 apparently someone is claiming that there appear chickens in the barn randomly (like the unicorn), so SPA is wondering if someone found evidence of such.

Comment: The heart thing is true, definitely, because it happened to me.

Comment: Have you got a screen, @Doorknob冰? if you have, please post it. I want to record all the cute eggs our staff gave us. Thanks!

Comment: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4320319#4320319

Comment: I got the heart as well. It took about 5 minutes or so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is now obsolete but should be preserved for historical reasons.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You mean those chickens?

[image: chick1]

Comment: Yep, those ones.

Comment: Now, I wonder if it is just pure RNG love or there is a trigger.

Comment: Why code in JS when you can just copy & paste them in? :p Unfortunately it's the work of photoshoping.

Comment: I hate you. Ok, I will update the question later.

Comment: Would you please add a notice in the answer about the photoshop thing? Just to increase visibility, some people skip comments

Comment: @balpha - See my answer below, I bet it **was** a reference to that question, right:P ?

Comment: Also, Tel, I will wait a little more to see if someone actually find something more, otherwise I will accept this answer since after all it was the one that made me post the question, even if only a troll.

Comment: @Derpy can't believe you really fell for this trap, the chickens themselves can be heard chirping "trolling! trolling!" :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard I did? I didn't? I just wanted to record a nice joke for the future to remember? You decide.

Comment: As promised, accepted until someone post something that can convince me to change this.

Comment: farmville chickens

Comment: [Chicken alert!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304285/241919)

Answer (score 14):

With original credit to Doorknob for providing the picture, I can confirm that the heart shape is indeed real (unlike the chickens, those were a troll by Telkitty).

[image]

Thanks to THelper suggestion, I can confirm that the trigger seem to be related to clicking (on the head?) of the stick figures: doing that, I was able to trigger the heart formation multiple times.
When the stickmen start forming the heart, you will notice they suddenly stop fighting each other.

I think to also know why this egg was added.
When the countdown to winterbash started, the site just contained a dark background, with the stickmen running around to form the numbers of a countdown.
Then, one use posted this question: [How do I interact with people?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270223/how-do-i-interact-with-people).

> I'm afraid I'm a little shy, and it's hard for me to find the right way to interact with the people.
>
> That said, I've tried several things, and nothing is working.
>
> For instance, when I click on one of them, they don't seem to notice. Waving the cursor over them doesn't alter their behavior either. Clicking and dragging yields no response.

I bet that balpha took the idea from there and decided to add something that would be triggered if someone tried to interact with these small ones.

*... now, why he didn't take my suggestion to replace those humans with some unicorns I don't know...*

Comment: I noticed the heart too when I first visited the leaderboard yesterday. I thought it was just a matter of waiting long enough so the little people can take their places. But, come to think of it, I did click on some of the little people to see if they would react, so that could be the trigger as well.

Comment: YES! It seem to be the click! Leave me some time to test, I think I got it.. and I also know why it was added...

Comment: I think I clicked primarily on the little people that were running.

Comment: ops, I will try to remember this one, sorry for capitalizing your name, balpha. It was an automatic thing

Comment: @SPArchaeologist Don't worry about it, my coworkers do it all the time. I've actually stopped correcting them most of the time :)

Comment: I think you have to click on at least one of the badges to bring up the detail modal before the heart will form.

Comment: @duozmo I believe you mean hats, and no, no such thing is required. Confirmed twice now that you just need to click the head of several running stickmen, then they start forming the heart.