# Winter bash 2016 easter eggs?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2016, easter-eggs

Over the course of the years, the winter bash site has featured multiple easter eggs. For example, in 2015, it was possible to force the stickmen walking around on the page to sit down in an heart formation.

Has anyone noticed something similar on the site this year?

As a reference, [here is a link to my original question about the egg from the 2015 edition of the bash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270899/the-quest-for-the-winter-chickens-of-the-bash).

Comment: You should try pressing Alt+F4 on the WinterBash leaderboard page.

Comment: @Glorfindel Hahahahahaha!

Comment: @Glorfindel funny `Ctrl` `W` works for me.

Comment: Not really an easter egg, but going to http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/hat gives a raw "404" response instead of the generic 404 page.

Comment: @Glorfindel you should get a hat for it.. haha