# Issue with winter bash 404 error page

Tags: bug, winter-bash-2016, 404-not-found

There is an issue with a particular link's 404 error page in the [Winter Bash 2016](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com)

For the invalid URLs we get the response as generic 404 error page.

Few examples:

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/hats

http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/test

But for the http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/hat URL, it returns the plain text 404, instead of the 404 error page.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: 404 plain text]

---

Credits to: [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289165/winter-bash-2016-easter-eggs#comment938644_289165)