# What was the blurry image the chicken posted?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2017, chicken

Now that the great secret of the Winter Chicken of the Bash [has been discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304391/the-quest-for-the-winter-chicken-of-the-bash-part-2/304800#304800), what was the following image the chicken posted for?

[image]

The chicken posted it 3 days before the two images that helped solve the mystery. What was it for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The image is part of header from winter bash site with a approximately 4.5 pixel radius Gaussian blur.

[image: Winter Bash 2017 header blurred]

Fading between the blurred and unblurred image helps show it better:

[image: Animation of unblurring image]