# Aren't there any Christmas themed hats this Winter Bash 2022?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash-2022

I went over to the [Winter Bash](https://winterbash2022.stackexchange.com/) site to see what other beauties can be unlocked. It surprised me that there aren't any Christmas themed hats, for instance a Santa cap or reindeer antlers.

Maybe the website is bugged. Because when I toggle between Winter/Summer all hats stay the same.

Am I missing something? Aren't there any Christmas themed hats this Winter Bash 2022?

Comment: see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422142/2777074

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We don't know yet. The hat for participating on Christmas Day may be a secret one, like [in 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304345/295232):

> Red Hat With White Fur Trim
>
> [image]
>
> > Participate in a site (vote, post a question, post an answer, etc...) while it's 2017-12-25 (Christmas day) anywhere in the world. The hat was first triggered on 2017-12-24 10:00AM UTC.

Comment: Well, looks like this theory is disproven.

Answer (score 3):

Along with secret hats being hidden, some hats simply aren't released until later, are tied to a particular date or holiday, require extra coding, or have [triggers that take a long time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304805/282094) to unlock.

Sometimes there is an [Easter Egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easter_egg_(media)) on the Winter Bash website featuring [The Chicken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270899/the-quest-for-the-winter-chickens-of-the-bash), other games or activities, Hat Dash or [knitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339896/winter-bash-2019-knitting) Christmas sweaters, require some tweaking and get released after the start of Winter Bash.

You never know until it's almost over what lies in store.

Comment: Indeed, there's [an easter egg](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62574380#62574380) planned for next week!

Comment: Thanks @Panda, I've added Easter Eggs to the answer.